# Access page header of the current page in javascript [no ajax]

Tags: javascript, html

How can I view the page headers of the loaded page using javascript.

Is there something where I can execute a

```
e.g. window.pageHeaders['session']
```

Note: I am not talking about a Ajax page load.

Comment: Are you talking about the content-headers or the javascript representation of the header-tag or what the header tag contains?

Comment: You could do this with [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API), but they're [poorly supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers) at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6DFNG/).

Linking from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-http-headers-in-javascript).

This answer by Raja will get the page headers for the current page.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
alert(headers);
```

Comment: This works, but what this does it that it makes an extra ajax call. How can I get the http headers without an extra ajax call ?

Comment: @PrakashRaman Do you use any server side language? You can set the headers to a javascript variable then.

Comment: That is what I am currently doing, which is my last resort. Was hoping there would be another way. BTW I am using PHP

Answer (score -1):

you doing something like this? please show us example implementation.

```
   <!--Save Headers-->
   <?php $currentHeaders = json_encode( getallheaders() ); ?>

   <!--Create Output Container-->
   <div id="output"></div>

   <!--Show Headers-->
   <button onclick="showheaders()">show headers</button>

   <!--Javascript Ugliness-->
   <script>
      function showheaders(){
         var headers = <?php echo $currentHeaders; ?>;

         // Collect your goodies here eg: var goodies = headers['proxy-authenticate'];
         console.log("Headers", headers);

         // See the output on screen?
         var output = document.getElementById('output');
            output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify( headers );
      }
   </script>
```